# How to show vim tab page title more clearly?

Tags: vim, neovim

I open several tab pages in vim in terminal, their titles are

```
s/core.py, s/order.py, s/m/order.py
```

But I want them to be shown as

```
serializers/core.py, serializers/order.py, starvation/models/order.py
```

or last 20 characters

```
serializers/core.py, serializers/order.py, tion/models/order.py
```

or last_dirname/filename

```
serializers/core.py, serializers/order.py, models/order.py
```

Answer (score 0):

Though, not exactly answering your question of showing the full name of file in the tab title.

You can use the below commands to display the full name of file as status bar in the file.

```
:set laststatus=2  #2 - to always display status bar. 1 - display if there are more than one window, 0 - don't display status bar
:set statusline=%F #%F - Full file name & %f - short file name
```

You can add the above to `.vimrc` file also, without `:`